# How to calculate increase in storage usage on Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How would I calculate or estimate the increased storage difference from increasing the precision on a column from number(2,0) to number(6,0)?  Or is it the same?  No difference?  Let's pretend I have 1 million rows in the table.  What does the arithmetic look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision of a number field is basically just a constraint on how much precision Oracle will retain when storing a value. The underlying number format is actually the same (it's a varying-width field, and not something like a fixed-sized integer or float) - the amount of space required is related to the number of digits in the specific numbers which are being stored.

So if you don't modify the values in the table, then the size shouldn't change. But if you increase the precision and then update the table with values with more digits, then they will potentially consume more space.